# Help with derivative of integral function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do you differentiate:
$\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{a}^{b}e^{x^{2}+t^{2}}dt$

I tried writing $f(x)$ as the difference of the antiderivative of the function $\displaystyle e^{x^{2}+t^{2}}$ and I get $\displaystyle e^{x^{2}+b^{2}}-e^{x^{2}+a^{2}}$ but I think this is wrong.

Can you help me please? Thank in advance.

Comment: Here $e^{x^2}$ "comes out." For more complex situations, please see Wikipedia, differentiation under the integral sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write
$$
f(x)=\int_{a}^{b}e^{x^{2}+t^{2}}dt=e^{x^{2}}\int_{a}^{b}e^{t^{2}}dt
$$ getting
$$
f(x)=C \cdot e^{x^{2}}
$$ where $C=\int_{a}^{b}e^{t^{2}}dt$ is **a constant** with respect to $x$. Then,  by the chain rule,

> $$
> f'(x)=2x e^{x^{2}} \cdot \int_{a}^{b}e^{t^{2}}dt.
> $$

Comment: ok I'm officially an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: @John11 If I had to count how many times I've been one...

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$f(x) = \int_a^b e^{x^2+t^2} dt =  \int_a^b e^{x^2} e^{t^2} dt = e^{x^2}\int_a^b  e^{t^2} dt$$

So $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 2xe^{x^2}\int_a^b  e^{t^2} dt = \int_a^b 2x e^{x^2+t^2} dt$$